# How can I log stdout and stderr into file, while showing stderr on screen, on bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have been writing some bash scripts, mostly to be used by automatic (crontab) operations. The common procedure is to log any output into a log file (which would be stored and emailed), by repeating commands such as:

```bash
logfile=/tmp/logs/$(basename "$0" .sh)-$(date +%Y%m%d).log
action1 >> "$logfile" 2>&1
hidden_action
action2 >> "$logfile" 2>&1
echo "message" >> $logfile
action3 >> "$logfile" 2>&1
```

I can probably just use `exec` so that the default behavior would be as expected without redirecting every line in which output is expected:

```bash
logfile=/tmp/logs/$(basename "$0" .sh)-$(date +%Y%m%d).log
exec > "$logfile" 2>&1
action1
hidden_action > /std/null
action2
echo "message"
action3
```

(is this okay?)

However, sometimes I need to run the script manually, and some scripts take several minutes (or even hours). So I would run them on background and `cat` or `tail` constantly the log file.

I know I can `tee` the output with a line such as

```bash
exec > >(tee -a "$logfile") 2>&1
```

However, I would like rather the following behavior:

1. `stdout` and `stderr` would be written on `$logfile` by default.
2. `stderr` would also be sent to screen.
3. I can send updates to screen without logging them.
4. I can hide

Something like:

```bash
logfile=/tmp/logs/$(basename "$0" .sh)-$(date +%Y%m%d).log
exec ... # SOMETHING
action1                      # any output logged, errors also to screen
echo "checkpoint" > $screen  # print only to screen, not logged
hidden_action > $null        # any output goes neither to log nor to screen
action2                      # any output logged, errors also to screen
echo "message"               # just logged
action3                      # any output logged, errors also to screen
```

If not possible to do it as default behavior, then for each line:

```bash
action1 >#any output logged, errors also to screen
echo "checkpoint"
hidden_action > /dev/null
action2 >#any output logged, errors also to screen
echo "message" >> "$logfile"
action3 >#any output logged, errors also to screen
```

Thank you in advance for any clue.

Comment: "2. `stdout` would also be sent to screen" or "showing stderr on screen"?

Comment: @Cyrus, right, it should have been `stderr`. I just corrected in the question.